# Problems with vehicle weight painting - some blue parts

Tags: weight-painting

I've been following the following tutorial to build a vehicle:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q0IYcsNXY7M&t=8s

It's been great but when I test the weighting of all the parts, I get 3 red wheels but the parts shown below are blue, and, blue-ish!

[image]

[image]

I know this is going to cause me issues as I've already tested it in Unreal Engine using my previous model that only had one red wheel, and that was the only wheel that worked.

Any help to get everything showing as red would be much appreciated, as I feel like I've tried everything!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your car, enter edit mode, select all vertices belonging to the chassis, go to properties/vertex tab, select the appropriate vertex group, which has the same name of the controlling bone, click assign.

Then do the same for the wheel.

[image]

Comment: Selecting all vertices was the missing piece of the puzzle, thanks you so much!